# Pandas groupby bins and weighted average

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df here named `df_merged`:

| index | count_date | time_gap | device | count | average_speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2018-12-05 | 1 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2018-12-05 | 2 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2018-12-05 | 3 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2018-12-05 | 4 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2018-12-05 | 5 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 154747 | 2023-05-04 | 92 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| 154748 | 2023-05-04 | 93 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| 154749 | 2023-05-04 | 94 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| 154750 | 2023-05-04 | 95 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |
| 154751 | 2023-05-04 | 96 | CAT17 | 0 | 0 |

The table in count and average_speed is populated but it doesn't show here in the sample.
Basically, the time gap reprensent 15 min. So 1 = 0h00, 2 = 0h15, 3 = 0h30,...

I would like to:

1. groupby bins:

   bins = [1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 33, 37, 41, 45, 49, 53, 57, 61, 65, 69, 73, 77, 81, 85, 89, 93]
2. sum counts by bin
3. calculate `average_speed` by bin:

   ```
   def average_speed_mean(x):
       try: 
           return np.average(x["average_speed"], weights=x["count"])
       except ZeroDivisionError:
           return 0
   ```
4. replace bins by time, so [0-4] = 0h00m00s, [5-8] = 1h00m00s,... with a datetime type

I know I should use the `pd.cut` with `bins` for step 1 and `labels` for step 4 but I'm currently clueless on how to do it.
As well as for label creation, I don't get how to automatically generate it with numpy or maybe list comprehension to make it easier.

Could you guys please enlight me here as I feel I'm stuck and don't know in what direction to go.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

i make minimal example `df`

```
data = {'time_gap': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 8}, 
        'avg_speed': {0: 10, 1: 20, 2: 10, 3: 20, 4: 20, 5: 40}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
time_gap    avg_speed
0   1       10
1   2       20
2   3       10
3   4       20
4   5       20
5   8       40
```

**Code**

```
labels = ['{}h00m00s'.format(i) for i in range(0, 2)]
g = pd.cut(df['time_gap'].sub(1), bins=range(0, 9, 4), labels=labels, right=False)
out = df.groupby(g)['avg_speed'].agg(['count', 'mean'])
```

`out`

```
            count   mean
time_gap        
0h00m00s    4       15.0
1h00m00s    2       30.0
```

---

**Update**

if you want labels to timedelta

```
labels = pd.to_timedelta(['{}h00m00s'.format(i) for i in range(0, 2)])
```

`labels`

```
TimedeltaIndex(['0 days 00:00:00', '0 days 01:00:00'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
```

or

```
labels = pd.timedelta_range('00:00:00', periods=2, freq='H')
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply but I don't feel it entirely fits my needs. 
Perhaps this wasn't clear from my side but I would ideally like to have a datetime type for the time_gap.
Besides, as for the average_speed, I don't see where it weights the mean based on count.
I would also like to have all my columns as a result. 

I'm editing my post to make sure it's clear.

Comment: You won't be able to convert `labels` to datetime, but converting them to timedelta isn't difficult. For the rest I guess you should make an example. Create a minimal and reproducible example and make desired output of example.